# Copying categorized colors from line object to point object using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, style

I have two layers in QGIS one with point geometry and one with line geometry. Both layers have the same value in the "identification_id" column so I want to copy the colors (categorized by the identification_id) from the point layer to the segment layer. If both were point layers (or line layers) I would just simply right click on the layers and copy and paste the style..

The layers contains hundreds of different values for the identification_id so making it by hand would take too long time..

Any suggestion?

Comment: You could try to save the layer style and load it for the other layer, though I do not know, whether styles are compatible between different geometries.

Comment: Unfortunally isnt that possible :( The point layer qml got properties like this "outline_color" and the line layer got properties like "line_style"..

Comment: Meh, should have know that.
To use a cartographic approach: How many different styles do you have? Do you need all of them? Generally speaking there ought to be no more than 7 different colors, maximum 10 in a map. Maybe you could reduce your styles and then simply "copy" them by choosing from the previously used colors.

Comment: Agreed! I had a few hundreds categories hence, most of the objects were in different areas of the map..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One method is to use **Python** and copy the values, symbol colour and label from the categorisation of the line layer to the point layer. We can store the line symbology attributes in a dictionary and create a new style using the stored values.

You can test the following code, changing the names of the layers and the field name:

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsSymbol, QgsRendererCategory, QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer
style_dict = {}
layer_1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Point example")[0]
renderer = layer_1.renderer()
if renderer.type() == "categorizedSymbol":
    for cat in renderer.categories():
        style_dict[cat.value()] = (cat.symbol().color(), cat.label())

categories = []
layer_2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Line example")[0]
for classes, (color, label) in style_dict.items():
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer_2.geometryType())
    symbol.setColor(QColor(color))
    category = QgsRendererCategory(classes, symbol, label)
    categories.append(category)

field = 'ID'
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer(field, categories)
layer_2.setRenderer(renderer)
layer_2.triggerRepaint()
```

---

Example:

[image: Example]

---

**Edit:**

If you want to also copy the same field name used in the line layer, replace:

```
field = 'ID'
```

with:

```
field = renderer.classAttribute()
```

Comment: Is there any method to get the "active field/column" from layer_1? Instead of `field = 'ID'` I want to write something like `field = layer_1.field`

Comment: @axel_ande - Edited post to mention how to copy the same field name :)

Comment: @Anaphory it works as it is expected after your edit.

Comment: Is it possible to make an expression with this code? So that it would be possible to render the layer2 directly in the category symbol using the expression?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem is by rule based style. This implementation isn't perfect but it get the colors correct, but all gets into the same category.

Add a new rule and name it, then press on ("simple line" or "simple marker") and then the equation symbol next to "Fill" and then edit.
I then used excel to write this next part

```
Case
WHEN identification_id=     6336(<-my unique numbers)    THEN color_rgb(    255 , 0 ,   0   )   
WHEN identification_id=     6667(<-my unique numbers)    THEN color_rgb(    250 ,   0   ,   0   )
(etc. dragged the different parts)
Else color_rgb(1,1,1)
End
```

Then a formula like this `=A2&B2&C2&D2&E2&F2&G2&H2&I2` to get it all into one column and pasted it all into the editor.